# WSO2 ESB : all of samples not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Problem:
I can't run any sample of WSO2 ESB (version 4.5.1)
Detail:
After I finish to config WSO2 ESB which follow the Installation Guide and ESB Sample setup.
I can access the ESB console via the link :

`https://localhost:9443/carbon/`

It's working well, but when I try to run the first sample by command:

```
ant stockquote
-Daddurl=http://127.0.0.1:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService
-Dtrpurl=http://localhost:8280 -Dsymbol=IBM -Dmode=quote
```

I got the error code:

> ERROR_CODE = 101504
>
> ERROR_MESSAGE = Connection timeout For :
>   127.0.0.1:9000 For Request : Axis2Request [Message ID : urn:uuid:0b3c9526-289f-4e65-a525-93ecb32f323d] [Status Completed :
>   false]

I think maybe the problem is related about the `axis2Server` but I not sure because I did follow the instructions

Question:

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you Started the Axis2 server and deploy the SimpleStockQuoteService

Comment: Yes. I started the Axis2 server and deploy the SimpleStockQuoteService  before i run the sample. The below information is log of process when i start the Axis2 server:[2012-11-22 09:06:52,217]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOL
istener} -  HTTP Listener started on port : 9000
[2012-11-22 09:06:52,217]  INFO {samples.util.SampleAxis2ServerManager} -  [Simp
leAxisServer] Started

Comment: In addition, after i finish to start the Axis2 server. I can telnet to address: 127.0.0.1 , port 9000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems StockQuote service not visible to the Axis client. can you check whether you can see stockquote service wsdl once you started esb and axis2 server properly.link [1] will open stockquote service wsdl.

```
1. http://127.0.0.1:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl
```